# How to specify scan area in zxing

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using zxing in android to scan a bar code. I have some requirement that barcode which i need to scan is written on the backside of product and i want to scan in that way that after scan, i can get the whole image which contain barcode and other useful as a scan result. [image]
I have did a test to get an result image after successful scan but i want to define a scan area so that it only capture when QRcode start show in bottom right corner only(to capture whole product information image) ? Is it possible that ?